# Does PES 2012 (PC) support 4 players in local multiplayer?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2012

I'd like to use four XBox 360 controllers to play with friends (local/offline).

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you not ask this exact same question yesterday (swap fifa 12 for pes 12)? It got closed.

Comment: @danRhul The first question was closed because it started off as a list game recommendation style question. It was then edited to just ask if FIFA and PES (PC) support 4 gamepads and Mulmoth was directed to ask two separate questions which is why this question is here. The other question currently has 4 reopen votes because it is a valid question now.

Comment: Being at Stack Overflow since over 2 years, I'm a little bit astonished how hypercritical this community is in comparison.
This seems a very valid and interesting question to me. So why downvote it? Because it misses the Diablo-3 tag?

Comment: @pixel No, it isn't. These are two seperate games.

Comment: @Mulmoth you're right - sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to play with up to four controllers in local multiplayer.
Be sure to check the "DirectInput" option on the "Controllers" if you want to use several XBox-360 controllers on one PC ([see this thread](http://forums.pesfan.com/showthread.php?222500-Pes2010-Demo-problems-with-Xinput)).